# Seperating object from each other

Tags: mesh, import, geometry, remesh

I'm a new blender user, and i would like to work on a motorcycle project.

I downloaded a 3d model of an Honda Hornet in STL file, but I would like to be able to separate easily the different parts, saddle, lights, wheels, reservoir.

When i import the STL file in Rhino, I can select the parts, but not in Blender.

Is there a way to isolate every part of the models in different objects/groups to work more effectively on the model?

Here some images and the link to the stl file :

https://cults3d.com/fr/mod%C3%A8le-3d/jeu/honda-hornet-motorbike-printable-vehicle-3d-digital-stl-file

https://ibb.co/0GHDGjS

https://ibb.co/7KcpFtv

https://ibb.co/1v2Rrbt

Comment: if all the parts are within the same object, you need to go in Edit mode, select a part with L and press P to separate, it will create a new object, switch back to Object mode, select this new object, go in Edit mode in order to work this new object

Comment: Thank you Moonboots ! It seems to do what i need !

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the parts are within the same object, you need to go in *Edit* mode, select a part with <kbd>L</kbd> and press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate, it will create a new object, switch back to *Object* mode, select this new object, go in *Edit* mode in order to work this new object.

If you want several meshes of the same object to be separate, select them or select all and choose *Separate by Loose Parts*.

To do the opposite, i.e. join several objects and therefore convert them into meshes within one object, select them and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.